# R SF: Transforming the format of sf geometry

Tags: r, r-sf

I don't know this is a bug or it's just I am too naive in using sf so I raise this question here. I just used st_sample and generate some random points for some polygons, the format of generated geometry column is something like:

```
c(lon = 149096.638762965, lat = 175644.870597937)
```

However, in the normal sf data frame which I generated from the shapefile, the geometry looks something like this:

```
c(151510.88605718, 177463.801340721)
```

I am wondering if such a format is interchangeable? If I want to bind the st_sample geometry points with my shapefile, can I just use the rbind as I did for most other columns?

Thanks very much for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the dimensions are named is not a problem in binding.

When binding real and sampled points you have to be sure of two things:

- the CRS of both objects needs to be the same (or a geometry problem ensues)
- the column names of both objects need to be the the same (or a general data frame issue happens); note that the geometry column of `sf::st_sample()` is by default named "x", which is not very friendly - you will likely want to change it to something like "geometry". For that consider `dplyr::select()`

To illustrate the point consider this piece of code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# NC counties - a shapefile shipped with the sf package
counties <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = T) 

# three semi-random cities in NC
cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

# three fully random points in NC
points <- counties %>% 
  filter(NAME == "Mecklenburg") %>%  # as in Charlotte of Mecklenburg-Strelitz
  st_transform(st_crs(cities)) %>%   # to put on the same page as cities
  st_sample(3) %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  mutate(name = "some random place nearby Charlotte, NC")

# a quick check
plot(st_geometry(counties)) # bacground
plot(st_geometry(cities), pch = 4, col = "red", add = T)
plot(st_geometry(points), pch = 4, col = "blue", add = T)
```

[image: a quick check]

```
# binding - note the rename of x column to geometry
final_bind <- cities %>% 
  rbind(select(points, name, geometry = x)) # note the rename in select!

str(final_bind)
# Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ name    : chr  "Raleigh" "Greensboro" "Wilmington" "some random place nearby Charlotte, NC" ...
#  $ geometry:sfc_POINT of length 6; first list element:  'XY' num  -78.6 35.8
#  - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
#  - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA
#  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "name"

# final overview - lo & behold! a single object!
mapview::mapview(final_bind)
```

[image: a final result of a bind operation]

Comment: Hello Jindra, thanks for your answer. I am wondering if you have done anything in the code "..- attr(*, "names")= chr "name" as it is not shown correctly on my screen? Through the existing code, the final_bind object still consist of geometry with two different format but I guess this won't affect the performance in the future?

Comment: I have indeed copied the names attribute wrongly! my bad! I have edited the answer so that the printout of the str() call looks more clear. And should you want to get rid of the last vestiges of the named coordinates consider `final_final <- st_transform(final_bind, 4326)`; the object already is in EPSG:4326, but the tranform will align the structure of the geometry column.

Comment: That's very clear! Thanks Jindra :) Have a nice day!